# Getting the old value of a asp.net control on postback

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I want to be able to find the old value of a asp.net control (textbox, checkbox etc) without relying on events (e.g. OnTextChange event). Something like "someTextboxControl.OldText"  would be perfect! I imagine that it is stored in the viewstate and need to somehow get at it via a custom control. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by Shrage was helpful, but it took some additional searching to make this solution work. I placed his code into the code behind within the namespace of the page I was working on. Additionally I had to register the control, and change update the control in question.

Register extended textboxex control; this goes right below the page directive

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="group" Namespace="ESM_Web_Portal" Assembly="ESM Web Portal" %>
```

Update the texbox you want to extend in the aspx page

```
    <group:TextBoxEx ID="txbEditPartNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("part_number") %>'></group:TextBoxEx>
```

Then in code behind I was able to use the extended TextBox control

```
    protected void CheckForExistingPartNumber(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomValidator cv = ((CustomValidator)sender);
        TextBoxEx tb = (TextBoxEx)cv.Parent.FindControl(cv.ControlToValidate);

        if (SupplyBLL.GetSupplyByPartNumber(e.Value) != null && tb.Text != tb.OldText)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextBoxEx:System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        public string OldText { get; set; }


        protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection)
        {
            OldText = Text;
            return base.LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection);
        }

    }
```